# How do I only update certain fields of a Firestore record using a model?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `friends` collection where I need to only update the `stat` and `modifiedDate` fields. I am using a model called `ModelFriend` to serve as a structure for records in this collection. I like that it forces me to structure every record the same, but sometimes I only want to change certain fields on an `UPDATE`. For a `WRITE`, that's a different story - every field should be filled out.

When I run my code below, it sets all other fields to `null` and gives me the values below for those 2 fields only. How can I update only these fields for an existing record and still use a model?

```dart
void updateFriendRecord(String friendDocID, String stat) async {
  final timestamp = getTimestamp();

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final friendRecord = firestore.collection(usersCollection).doc(currentUID).collection(friendsCollection).doc(friendDocID);
  final data = ModelFriend(
    stat: stat,
    modifiedDate: timestamp,
  ).toJson();

  await friendRecord.update(data);
}

class ModelFriend {
  final String? createDate;
  final String? modifiedDate;
  final String? stat;
  final String? uid;
  final String? username;
  final bool? sendFriendRequest;

  ModelFriend({
    this.createDate,
    this.modifiedDate,
    this.stat,
    this.uid,
    this.username,
    this.sendFriendRequest,
  });

  ModelFriend.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic>? json)
      : //Transform JSON into model
        createDate = json?['createDate'] as String,
        modifiedDate = json?['modifiedDate'] as String,
        stat = json?['stat'] as String,
        uid = json?['uid'] as String,
        username = json?['username'] as String,
        sendFriendRequest = json?['sendFriendRequest'] as bool;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        //Transforms model into JSON
        'createDate': createDate,
        'modifiedDate': modifiedDate,
        'stat': stat,
        'uid': uid,
        'username': username,
        'sendFriendRequest': sendFriendRequest,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ModelFriend`'s `toJson` method. Try the following:

```dart
void updateFriendRecord(String friendDocID, String stat) async {
  final timestamp = getTimestamp();

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final friendRecord = firestore.collection(usersCollection).doc(currentUID).collection(friendsCollection).doc(friendDocID);
  final data = {
    "stat": stat,
    "modifiedDate": timestamp,
  };

  await friendRecord.update(data);
}
```

Comment: Yea this was my plan Z. I was hoping there was a way to use the model though.